# Webkit translate3d makes my text blurred

Tags: css, translate3d

After trying all the answers to similar posts on here, I've still had no luck with fixing my problem.

When I use -webkit-transform: translate3d on elements with text, the text blurs quite significantly. I've replicated the problem below via jsfiddle, but only appears if at a certain width (try resizing the browser to see the problem)

http://jsfiddle.net/H4JAM/

```
<div class="blur-percentage">Text with percentage</div>
<div class="blur-fixed">Text with fixed</div>

.blur-percentage {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%,0,0);
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.blur-percentage.move {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(50%,0,0);
}

.blur-fixed {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0,0);
    font-family: Arial;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.blur-fixed.move {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(200px,0,0);
}

$('.blur-percentage').on('click' , function() {
    $(this).addClass('move')
})

$('.blur-fixed').on('click' , function() {
    $(this).addClass('move')
})
```

Also - a screenshot of the problem..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jncSK.png

It's happening when a percentage is given rather than a fixed number, ie - 50%, not 200px.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: If you use 2d translate with `translate(50%,0)` instead of `translate3d(50%,0,0)`, you'll see it's rendered fairly OK. `translate3d` may try to render the text at the location even with an offset of a half pixel, so it will be blurred. Anti-aliasing always makes things blurred and it's good in some case. `translate` may just round the result of `50%` (to an integer) before rending.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can now see why it's blurring on percentage.. Due to the half pixel business. I'm still getting the same problem with 2d translate. Any tricks to render the fonts correctly. I just tried -webkit-font-smoothing: none, and it fixes the blur but makes the font look terrible.

Comment: I'm not sure about other kinds of transform (such as scale, skew), but I tried with just `translate(50%,0)` on my side and it does not look blurry at all (tested on both Opera 22 and Chrome 36).

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I think it's happening still because there are other elements on my page which are using translate3d, and it's booting up the 3d engine.. Could be wrong. Really need to find a work around for the text!